# python error : 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Tags: python, sockets

this is my python code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    import socket  
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
    sock.connect(('0.0.0.0', 4000))  
    import time  
    time.sleep(2)  
    #sock.send('1')
    print sock.recv(1024)  
    sock.close()
```

it show :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\test\test\python\client.py", line 3, in <module>
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

what can i do ,

thanks

**updated:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\test\test\python\client.py", line 4, in <module>
    sock.connect(('0.0.0.0', 4000))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: (10049, "Can't assign requested address")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While creating a socket object on Windows you should do:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

`AF_INET` for Internet addresses, and `AF_UNIX` for UNIX inter-process communication. The latter is obviously only available on UNIX platforms.

Also, follow [this example](http://effbot.org/librarybook/socket.htm) to find how to implement a simple socket server and client.

Comment: but i want to content  the ip : 0.0.0.0  , so  this is  a localhost ip  , yes  ?  what can i choose .

Comment: Instead of 0.0.0.0, use "" it binds to all the interfaces to localhost. I also think an example for implmenting a basic Socket Server and Client might be useful to you. Updating the answer with example.