# python socket error: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

Tags: python, sockets, networking, socket.io, network-programming

I have this short program:

```
import sys
import socket

target = "google.co.uk"
port = 443
print(target)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(target)
print("successfull connection to: " + target)
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
    s.connect(target)
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str
```

When I tried to change the line to: `s.connect(target,443)` 
I also got an error:

```
    s.connect(target,443)
TypeError: connect() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the function receives as a parameter is a tuple and thus a tuple should be given as a parameter. Meaning instead `f(a,b)` call the function with `f((a,b))`

And so, we fix your code like this:

```
import sys
import socket

target = "google.co.uk"
port = 443
print(target)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((target, port))
print("successfull connection to: " + target)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. From the [connections.py](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py) file from PyMySQL there's a function named `connect()` line with

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(self.connect_timeout)
sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
```

A Windows user will get

> AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

To [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5088126/5675325) one should change the first line to

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

This will then get

```
File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 609, in connect
    sock.connect(self.windows_socket)
TypeError: connect(): AF_INET address must be tuple, not str
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651380/5675325), one just need to have the third line changed to

```
sock.connect((self.unix_socket))
```

so you should have

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(self.connect_timeout)
sock.connect((self.unix_socket))
```

Comment: You need to add a coma after the first item of a tuple if you only have one item otherwise python3 will interpret the parenthesis around the item as superfluous and it will read the param as a string.